# Does dsp:input supports onclick?

Tags: javascript, atg, oracle-commerce

I was trying to use `dsp:input` tag with type as button on an jsp page.

Does the `dsp:input` tag supports `onclick` function??

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/PageDevGuide/html/s1218dspinput01.html), no:

```
<dsp:input [type="input-control"] [name="input-name"]
   bean="property-spec" ["source-spec"]
   [checked="{true|false}"]
   [default="value"]
   [priority=integer-value]
/>
```

You can try to define your input with:

```
<dsp:input>
    <dsp:tagAttribute name="onclick" value="..." />
</dsp:input>
```

Comment: Thank you @hsz. Is there any other way that i can use onclick function here??

Comment: Thank you @hsz. But the onclick function is working normally in the dsp:input tag itself

Answer (score 0):

As the `dsp:input` behaves as the normal **HTML** input control. It supports the `**onclick**` function too.